# getting the missing numbers in array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the missing numbers of an array list, array list gets its numbers from firebase database, so I need to get the missing numbers that are not in the array.
Numbers are in between 1-10 and arrayList contains[3,9,7,5] so it will print "1 2 4 6 8 10" to a list view.
my code it just duplicates the numbers from 1-10 four times for each number. so how can I do this in android.
... here is my code

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                students = ds.getValue(Students.class);
                studentSeatNum = students.getSeatnum();

                arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(studentSeatNum));// save numbers from fire-base database into array list
            }
            // get missing values of the array list
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
                    if (i != arrayList.indexOf(j)) {
                        array.add(String.valueOf(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EmptySeats.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does your code not work?

Comment: it duplicate the numbers from 1-10 four times @Carcigenicate

Comment: Missing in what way? You're also missing 100, 12345 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, to name a few of the 4 billion-odd missing values.

Comment: @AndyTurner , the numbers are in between 1-10 , array list contains [3,9,7,5], print the missing numbers that are not in array

Comment: @ReemH.Alzoubi please [edit] your question to include relevant details.

Comment: @AndyTurner done...Did you understand the problem?

Comment: @ReemH.Alzoubi yes.

Comment: @AndyTurner so any suggestions?

Comment: @ReemH.Alzoubi just add indexes which aren't in the other list. You probably want to use `contains` rather than `indexOf`.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).filter(o -> !arrayList.contains(o)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @AndyTurner yes you are right thanks... it finally worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

If the list will **always** have numbers between **1-10**, for example: `[3,7,9]`, use a simple for-loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
   if (!list.contains(i)){
      otherlist.add(i);
   }
}
```

## Output

the `otherlist` will contain `[1,2,4,5,6,8,10]`

## Explanation

the `.contains()` method checks if the list already has a certain number, if it does not, you simply add that number (in the examples case, **i** - the index of the loop), to `otherlist`.